# An algorithm for Gaussian integers

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

> **Question** : Let $i^2=-1$. If a pair $(a+bi, c+di) (a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z, a\not\equiv b, c\not\equiv d\ \text{(mod 2)})$ such that $a+bi$ and $c+di$ are **relatively prime** is given, then can we say that repeating the following operation leads $(1,1)$ in finitely many steps?
>
> Suppose that $a+bi$ and $c+di$ are relatively prime if and only if $a+bi$ and $c+di$ don't have any common divisor except for $\pm 1,\pm i$.
>
> **Operation** : If a pair $(a+bi, c+di)$ is given (we may suppose that $N(a+bi)\le N(c+di)$ where $N(a+bi)=a^2+b^2$), the next pair is defined as $(a+bi, (c+di)+\epsilon (1+i)(a+bi))$ with an appropriate choice of $\epsilon=\pm 1,\pm i$.

**Example** : Noting that $3+2i$ and $4+i$ are relatively prime since each of them is a prime, we know that the pair $(3+2i,4+i)$ satisfies the condition above. Noting that $N(3+2i)\le N(4+i)$, 
$$\begin{align}
(3+2i,4+i) & \rightarrow (3+2i,-1+2i)\ \ \ \ (\because \ \ (4+i)+(+i)(1+i)(3+2i)=-1+2i)\\
 & \rightarrow (2-i, -1+2i)\ \ \ \  (\because \ \ (3+2i)+(+i)(1+i)(-1+2i)=2-i)\\ 
 & \rightarrow (2-i,-i)\ \ \ \  (\because \ \ (-1+2i)+(-i)(1+i)(2-i)=-i)\\
 & \rightarrow (1,-i)\ \ \ \  (\because \ \ (2-i)+(-1)(1+i)(-i)=1)\\ 
 & \rightarrow (1,1)\ \ \ \ (\because \ \ (-i)+(+1)(1+i)(+1)=1).
\end{align}$$

**Motivation** : I've been looking for a similar algorithm for [Gaussian integers $\mathbb Z[i]$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer)  as Euclidean Algorithm for rational integers $\mathbb Z$. Then, I reached the operation above. However, I'm facing difficulty for proving or disproving that repeating the operation leads $(1,1)$ for any pair. Can anyone help?

**Edit 1** : As Gerry Myerson pointed out, the Euclidean algorithm works fine in the Gaussian integers.

**Edit 2** : I think if we can prove the following lemma, then we can say that repeating the operation leads $(1,1)$ in finitely many steps. However, I'm facing difficulty for proving the lemma. Can anyone help?

**Lemma** : If a pair $(a+bi, c+di) (a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z, a\not\equiv b, c\not\equiv d\ \text{(mod 2)})$ such that $a+bi$ and $c+di$ are relatively prime with $N(a+bi)\le N(c+di)$ is given , then we can get 
$$N(c+di+\epsilon (1+i)(a+bi))\lt N(c+di)$$
with an appropriate choice of $\epsilon=\pm 1,\pm i$.

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm works just fine in the Gaussian integers. Given $a,b$, $b\ne0$, there exist $q,r$ with $a=bq+r$ and norm of $r$ less than norm of $b$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thank you very much for pointing it out. The algorithm of this question might be another form of the Euclidean algorithm, but I don't have any good idea.

Comment: Is it $a+b$ or $a+bi$ in your lemma ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Thank you very much for pointing it out. $a+bi$ is correct.

Comment: Your lemma is not correct if $N(a+bi)=N(c+di)$. For example let $a=b=c=d=1$, so I think it should be $N(a+bi)< N(c+di)$ or change this: $N(c+di+\epsilon (1+i)(a+bi))\leq N(c+di)$

Comment: @FarshadNahangi: $a+bi,c+di$ have to satisfy the following two conditions(I wrote these at the top of the question). 1)$a\not\equiv b, c\not\equiv d\ \text{(mod $2$)}$ 2)$a+bi$ and $c+di$ are relatively prime. (The way I wrote might be misleading, sorry. I edited.) So, your example does not satisfy these conditions. I think these conditions seem to be a key. By the way, as you say, the case $N(a+bi)=N(c+di)$ seems to have difficulty.

Comment: I don't understand the conditions that $a\not\equiv b$ and $c\not\equiv d$ modulo $2$. They may save your lemma, but they could also render it useless (unless you have another operation up your sleeve). If after one step the congruence is no longer satisfied (which as far as I can see could well happen), how would you proceed? And _why_ did you introduce he condition (what would the equivalent condition be when doing Euclid's algorithm in $\Bbb Z$)?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: First, I think the congruence will be satisfied. We have four possibilities as $(c\pm a\pm b)+(d\pm b\pm a)i$ with an appropriate choice of signs. Then, we know $\pm a\pm b\equiv \pm b\pm a$, so $c\pm a\pm b\not\equiv d\pm b\pm a$ since $c\not\equiv d$. Second, I reached the conditions when I've tried to make the operation meaningful.  (As you pointed out, this may not be related to the Euclid algorithm.)

Comment: @mathlove : O.K. I got it but the problem still alive for two relatively prime numbers $a+bi$ and $b+ai$, because $N(a+bi)=N(b+ai)$, but I don't know when two complex numbers are relatively prime.

Comment: @FarshadNahangi: First, I added some explanation about "relatively prime". Second, I think your example does not have any problem. A pair $(a+bi,b+ai)$ satisfy the conditions(suppose that this pair are relatively prime). Hence, we have four possibilities as $a+(2a+b)i, (2b-a)-bi,(a+2b)+bi,-a+(2a-b)i$. Here, supposing that $|2a+b|\ge |b|$ and $|2b-a|\ge |a|$ and $|2b+a|\ge|a|$ and $|2a-b|\ge|b|$, we get $a(a+b)\ge 0, b(a+b)\ge 0, b(b-a)\ge 0, a(b-a)\le 0$. Hence, we can see $ab\ge 0$ from the first two. On the other hand, we can see $ab\le 0$ from the last two. (continued)

Comment: (part 2) These lead $ab=0$ , which is "$a=0$ or $b=0$". If $a=0$, then since the initial pair $(bi,b)$ has to be relatively prime, $b=\pm 1$. This case leads $(1,1)$. If $b=0$, we get the same conclusion. Hence, the case that either $|2a+b|\lt |b|$  or $|2b−a|\lt |a|$  or $|2b+a|\lt |a|$  or $|2a−b|\lt |b|$  holds is left. This means that the operation does work; we can have $(a+bi,b+ai)\rightarrow (a+bi,p+qi)$  such that $N(p+qi)\lt N(b+ai)$ . Hence, I think your example is not a counterexample of both the lemma and the operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need some lemmas before concentrating on what matters. We shall prove the norm is always decreasing and is always nonzero in your situation. This would imply your claim if we can guarantee the algorithm never "chokes", i.e. we rule out the equality part. This can be made with additional informations.

**Lemma.** Let $t=1+i$. For every complex numbers $m,n$ it is possible to find a linear combination $\alpha$ of $\varepsilon t$ such that $$N(n-\alpha m)\leqslant N(m).$$

To prove the lemma, imagine the complex plane, the number $m$ and the number $n$, possibly very far away from $m$. Write the linear combinations of the numbers $mt, mit, -mt, -mit$. They cover the complex plane with squares of sides $|m|\sqrt{2}$. By the pigeonhole principle, $n$ is at most $|m|$ from another complex number, say, $\alpha m$. This implies $N(n-\alpha m)\leqslant N(m)$, as we wanted.

---

**Lemma.** If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, $N(a-\alpha b)\lt N(b)$.

Suppose $N(a-\alpha b)=N(b)$. Following the idea of the first lemma, it follows that $a$ is in the center of a square of the covering we created. Now, consider the covering of all gaussian multiples of $b$. It contains all centers and all vertices, and, then, $a=kb$, contradiction.

---

**Lemma**. The norm $N(a-\alpha b)$ is always nonzero.

Suppose it is zero. Therefore, $a=\alpha b$, so they aren't relatively prime, contradiction.

---

Therefore, we proved the norm is decreasing and is always nonzero. This implies your algorithm always terminates in $(1,1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have two questions. 1)About the proof of $n=km\iff N(n-\alpha m)=0$. $\Leftarrow $ is easy, but in order prove $\Rightarrow $, we need to prove that $k$ is a linear combination of $\epsilon (1+i)$, don't we? I would like you to show the proof because I'm facing difficutly. (continued)

Comment: (part 2)2)About the second lemma, you use $N(a−\alpha b)=N(b)\iff N(n−\alpha m)=N(m)$, don't you? Then, I understand your second sentence "Following ⋯  created". But I can't understand the following sentences. Especially, "It contains all centers and all vertices". I don't know why you can say so. Could you please explain more about this?

Comment: @mathlove for the first question: this situation does not happen in the restrictions you wrote, so this part is unnecessary, I'm sorry. Here's why: in order to prove $k=\gamma (1+i)$, we need at least $N(k)=N(\gamma)N(1+i)=2N(\gamma).$ This would imply $N(n)$ is even, but it isn't, since exactly one of $\Re(n)$ or $\Im(n)$ is odd. In fact, what I wrote isn't true in general, I apologize. However, it doesn't break the argument in any way.

Comment: @mathlove for the second question: drawing helps a lot. You say you understand $n$ is in the center of a square. Call two opposite vertices $A=\alpha (1+i)b$ and $C=\gamma(1+i)b$. Therefore, $a=\frac{A+C}{2}$. However, because they are opposite vertices, we have $$C-A=2\varepsilon b\implies C=A+2\varepsilon b\implies a=A+\varepsilon b\implies b\mid a.$$ This contradicts the fact that they are relatively prime.

Comment: Thanks. I have two questions, again:). 1)I think $n=\frac{A+C}{2}$ instead of $a=\frac{A+C}{2}$ since $n$ is in the center. Am I mistaken? 2)Why do you get $C-A=2\epsilon b$? I get $2\epsilon$. Maybe am I drawing another figure? I'm thinking a figure made of the linear combinations of the numbers $mt,mit,−mt,−mit$. I'm afraid that you're thinking of a different figure.

Comment: I [drew some multiples](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQqqm.png) of $z_2=(1+2i)(1+i)$, I think it will help. Imagine also the multiples of $z_1=1+2i$ and how they are the centers, the vertices and the median of the sides of these squares.

Comment: I think I got it! I'm going to write how I understood it. Please check it. From the 1st lemma, we get $N(a-\alpha b)\le N(b)$ since the 1st lemma holds for every complex numbers $m,n$. In the proof of the 2nd lemma, we consider the linear combinations of the numbers $bt,bit,-bt,-bit$ instead of $mt,mit,-mt,-mit$!(this is obvious,sorry, now I got it). So, supposing $N(a-\alpha b)=N(b)$ tells us that $a$ is in the center of a square of the covering. Since the multiples of $b$ covers every centers and vertices of the covering, a contradiction. Thank you so much! Your explanation was perfect!

Comment: @mathlove I'm glad you liked it! Is there any more problems about the answer?

Comment: No more problems. I learned a lot from your answer. Thank you very much!